# How to run different class simultaneously or non-blocked in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a 3 different classes which i want to run simultaneously.

```
 public static void takeStatus() throws IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        static double [][] askbid_box = new double [2][6];
        Double newqty = 0.01;
    //case 1

    if(Alarm[0]>0) {
        A.sell(askbid_box[0][0], newqty);
        B.buy(askbid_box[1][2], newqty);
    }
    //case 2
    if(Alarm[0]>0) {
        C.sell(askbid_box[0][2], newqty);
        A.buy(askbid_box[1][0], newqty);            

} //end
```

In specific, the code have to run simultaneously

(A.sell and B.buy) at the same time or non-blocked

(C.sell and A.buy) at the same time or non-blocked

I know the potential solution is a Thread or Runnable.

But I don't know how to code it. please help.

Comment: Try to check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Welcome to the community. This is probably not a good fit for this community as it is rather broad rather than a specific programming problem. Threading and concurrency can be a complex topic; I recommend checking out this resource: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html. Also, you may want to view the Help section of StackOverflow for more details about asking a question that is a good fit for the website: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Do some basic research, you know about Thread and Runnable so finding reading material and tutorials to get you started should be easy.

Comment: You don't "run classes." -1 from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CountDownLatch countDown = new CountDownLatch(1);

new Thread(() -> {
    countDown.await();
    A.sell(askbid_box[0][0], newqty);
}).start();
new Thread(() -> {
    countDown.await();
    B.buy(askbid_box[1][2], newqty);
}).start();

countDown.countDown();
```

This creates a countdownlatch and two threads, makes threads wait on the latch to signal, and starts them simultaneously.

`countDown.await();` means that thread waits until `countDown.countDown();` is invoked

Comment: Thanks Kitaec very much.